# Circular Progress Indicator in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple carousel to display some images. As you would expect the carousel auto rotates every x seconds.

I currently have a div which I animate the width over the x seconds to show progress. This allows users to see how long they have to wait until the next image is displayed. When a user hovers over the image, the progress bar shrinks. When they mouse out, it begins to fill again.

However, rather than use a boring bar, I wanted to try and use a circle. Kind of like a spinning circle you see whilst ajax is loading. I have no idea how to do this.

Can anyone help? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generate a series of images representing the different degrees you'd like to represent, making the distinctions as fine-grained as you'd like. You could make four images representing 0%, 25%, 75%, and 100% "progress" or a hundred images representing each 1% difference.

In JavaScript, rather than changing the width of a bar, you can then swap in the appropriate image for the current amount of progress.  `if (progress < 25) image = '0percent.png';` (et cetera).

Doing this without using images would be possible on some modern browsers with HTML 5 support, but entirely impractical anywhere else.

Note that this is quite different than the standard "loading" graphic. Those spinners do not represent progress at all, since they just spin repeatedly until the document loads. Spinners are therefore made as animated GIFs, so a single image can simply sit on the page, spinning merrily, until it's removed.

Comment: I ended up using setInterval to update the background image. Thanks very much!

Answer (score 4):

To avoid the clutter of *n* gifs/pngs for every step of the progress indicator, create a single sprite of all the steps and stack them up horizontally or vertically (e.g. if your progress indicator is 40x40 and you want to show 8 steps, create a 320x40 image, and put them by increasing value back-to-back from left to right).

Create a new element with its dimensions fixed to a single step's size (40x40 in the example) and put this sprite as its background image.

Then when you receive the ticks from the Timer (or `setTimeout/Interval`), shift the background-image's `position-x` property by one size (0, 40, 80, 120, etc.).

This is much faster than having a separate image for every step and the end-user immediately pre-loads the entire sprite on the first event.

Comment: I'd put them in a square rather than horizontal/vertical... requires a bit more math to make work, but its pretty easy with the modulus operator. Why you say?! I don't know.. easier to view in photoshop.

Comment: Hear hear! +1 for sprites and for programmatic sprite switching.

Answer (score 2):

You could use SVG, or canvas.

There also [libraries](http://raphaeljs.com/) that can do it (like [this](http://raphaeljs.com/polar-clock.html)?)

Comment: Great in theory, however I have a somewhat decent machine (quad core, 4GB RAM) and trying to use Chrome developer tools on that polar clock page just made my computer nearly die!

Maybe in the next few years SVG will become more viable?

Comment: Isn't it the problem of chrome developer tools, or something? It worked fine in my firefox (with a dual core cpu, not even using 100% of any of the cores).

Comment: RaphaelJS is compatible with all browsers, even IE6+.

Answer (score 1):

You inspired me to make a manually controlled progress indicator. I made a [demo of it here](http://jsfiddle.net/AwbXz/). Then I started tweeking and decided to turn it into a plugin. The plugin includes a timer as well as a few other options. Check out the [plugin demo](http://wowmotty.blogspot.com/2010/06/dynamic-progress-indicator.html), maybe this will work for you?

Comment: Cool demo. Thats a great way to do it! Although I need a solid doughnut shape loader, so the multiple images wont work, but a really good approach!